# Convert Date Ranges into a Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have data in the following format:

```
    BEG_DT      END_DT      REGION
0   2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
1   2020-06-29  2021-06-09  region_a
2   2020-01-01  2020-06-29  region_a
3   2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_b
4   2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_b
5   2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
6   2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
7   2020-07-08  2021-06-09  region_a
8   2020-01-01  2020-07-08  region_a
9   2021-05-10  2021-06-09  region_a
10  2020-01-01  2021-05-10  region_a
11  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
12  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
13  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
14  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
15  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
16  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
17  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_b
18  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
19  2020-02-10  2021-06-09  region_a
20  2020-01-01  2020-02-10  region_a
21  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
22  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_b
23  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
24  2020-05-31  2021-06-09  region_b
25  2020-01-01  2020-05-31  region_b
26  2020-07-31  2021-06-09  region_a
27  2020-03-01  2020-07-31  region_a
28  2020-01-01  2020-03-01  region_a
29  2021-03-08  2021-06-09  region_a
30  2020-03-31  2021-03-08  region_a
31  2020-01-01  2020-03-31  region_a
32  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
33  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
34  2020-12-31  2021-06-09  region_a
35  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  region_a
36  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
37  2021-03-17  2021-06-09  region_a
38  2020-01-01  2021-03-17  region_a
39  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
40  2021-03-31  2021-06-09  region_b
41  2020-01-01  2021-03-31  region_b
42  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
43  2020-05-31  2021-06-09  region_b
44  2020-01-01  2020-05-31  region_b
45  2021-05-08  2021-06-09  region_c
46  2021-03-31  2021-05-08  region_c
47  2020-12-31  2021-03-31  region_c
48  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  region_a
49  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
```

Each row represents a duration that a given id exists in a given region.

How do I pivot from date ranges into a time series?

The date ranges should be resampled into a single timeseries index.

The REGION column should be pivoted into three columns ('region_a', 'region_b', 'region_c')

The values should be the count of records where the new index falls between the BEG_DT and the END_DT of the original record.

```
             region_b    region_a   region_c
2020-01-01   9000        8000       1000
2020-01-02   8940        7932       1128
...
2021-06-09   8067        7062       2871
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
periods =  pd.date_range(df.BEG_DT.min(), df.END_DT.max(), freq="W-MON")
pd.DataFrame({p: df.query("BEG_DT < @p & @p <= END_DT").REGION.value_counts() for p in periods}).T
```

I'll need to do some testing as to whether it's faster.

For some additional context, this dataset contains 13M records.

Comment: Nice! I haven't worked with `query` so far, but now I'm convinced that I need to look into it. Looking forward to your timing measurements.

Comment: It's not so different from df[(df["BEG_DT"]< p) & (df["BEG_DT"] <= p)], but I've read that it's faster when you have multiple conditionals or a lot of records.

Comment: Well...uh...so far it's three minutes vs. much, much, longer than three minutes.

Comment: I think it's time to cancel it.

Comment: Oh dear, that bad :((

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure if I understand your intention correctly, but maybe the following helps you find a solution.

With the DataFrame `df` from the data you have given

```
        BEG_DT      END_DT    REGION
0   2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
1   2020-06-29  2021-06-09  region_a
2   2020-01-01  2020-06-29  region_a
... ...         ...         ...
47  2020-12-31  2021-03-31  region_c
48  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  region_a
49  2020-01-01  2021-06-09  region_a
```

this

```
def dates_range(row):
    return pd.date_range(start=row.iat[0], end=row.iat[1], freq='D')

df['DATE'] = df.apply(dates_range, axis='columns')
df = df[['DATE', 'REGION']].explode('DATE')
df['COUNT'] = 1
df = df.pivot_table(index='DATE', columns='REGION', aggfunc='sum')
```

gives you the following result (`print(df)`):

```
              COUNT                  
REGION     region_a region_b region_c
DATE                                 
2020-01-01     27.0      7.0      NaN
2020-01-02     27.0      7.0      NaN
2020-01-03     27.0      7.0      NaN
2020-01-04     27.0      7.0      NaN
2020-01-05     27.0      7.0      NaN
...             ...      ...      ...
2021-06-05     26.0      7.0      1.0
2021-06-06     26.0      7.0      1.0
2021-06-07     26.0      7.0      1.0
2021-06-08     26.0      7.0      1.0
2021-06-09     26.0      7.0      1.0
```

What is happening: The `apply` creates for each row in `df` a range with the dates that are contained in the interval `[BEG_DT, END_DT]` and stores it in the column `DATE`. In the next step the ranges in `DATE` get "exploded". The resulting long DataFrame has 2 columns, one - `DATE` - with all the dates from the lists and another one - `REGION` - with the corresponding region. Then a column - `COUNT` - gets added, just for the counting in the next `pivot_table` step.

Does that make sense?

**EDIT**:

If the use of `explode` is too memory intensive then this

```
from collections import Counter

def count_dates(row):
    return Counter(pd.date_range(row.iat[0], row.iat[1], freq='D'))

df['COUNT'] = df.apply(count_dates, axis='columns')
df = df[['REGION', 'COUNT']].groupby('REGION').sum()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
            region: count
            for region, count in df.itertuples()
        })
```

or a bit shorter

```
...
df['COUNT'] = df.apply(count_dates, axis='columns')
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
            region: sum(group.COUNT, Counter({}))
            for region, group in df[['REGION', 'COUNT']].groupby('REGION')
        })
```

could be an alternative. The result should be the same.

Last edit: Changed a few names in the alternative solutions to better reflect the adjusted mechanic.

Comment: I think so. Explode is a neat function. I know I've come across it, but this is the first time I've seen how it could be useful.

Comment: I think this might blow up the size of the DataFrame too much.

Comment: @JoshuaFarina If the size of the DataFrame gets too big then the version I've just added might be an option.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think with some tweaking, this could work.

Comment: I came up with something a bit different, but I intend to compare approaches when I have time. Let me know what you think.